# How to add a pdf document properties to the document with workflow

Tags: workflow, document, library

I have a document library for pdf invoices, on SP 2010. I have a code and an approver for each document, which I have them as the document properties.
Is there any way to add the name of approver and the code to the PDFs after approval? I have an approval workflow. Let say is there any workflow to add a document properties to the actual document while it is pdf?